# Inverted transparency on COLLADA export

Tags: export, transparency, collada, osx

I have a model that has a few objects with transparent materials. On exporting to COLLADA I noticed that the transparency appears inverted when viewing the file with other tools (so far I have tried Preview on OS X, Autodesk's online A360 Viewer and the SceneKit rendering engine).

I checked the exported COLLADA file and the value for alpha are the same as in the Blender project but it seems that every other tool is interpreting this value differently than Blender (alpha value 1 is considered 100% opaque in Blender and 100% transparent in the other programs I used).

Is this expected when exporting from Blender projects? Is there a way to reverse the alpha for materials that have transparency?

Comment: just a guess : can that be due to inverted normals ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case.